# Firefox css moz-transform scale down a div, the border information is lost

Tags: html, css, transform

Open the below html in firefox, you can see the right and bottom border is missing, but Chrome/IE is good, is that a bug exist in firefox or I can use some other method to make it look the same with Chrome/IE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style> 
* {font-size:20px}
div
{
   width:400px;
   height:400px;
   background-color:lightgreen;
   border:1px solid black;
   transform-origin:0 0;
   -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
   -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
   transform:scale(0.7);
   -moz-transform:scale(0.7);
   -ms-transform:scale(0.7); 
   -webkit-transform:scale(0.7); 
}
</style>

</head>
<body style='margin:10px;padding:10px'><div>Hello. This is a DIV element.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might not be the problem, but [it's better to put non-prefixed version at last, not first](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/).

Comment: when i use border:4px solid red; than it works :-)

Comment: 4px works, but not if you scale the 1px border down, i guess firefox just not render the border small than 1px.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues in Firefox with borders not being rendered correctly when using `transform: scale()`. Adding a really tiny `border-radius` solved the issue for me.

```
border-radius: 0.01px;
```

I guess it forces the renderer to use another method for rendering borders.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot problems with the box-model if you use scale to decrease the size of a div.

Here is my solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/zHpbm/1/

```
div { 
 padding:1px;
}
```

add a 1px padding to your div and the box-model becomes back his normal size.

Be careful, i only fix it in the fiddle for -moz- , so don't be confused if you open the link in chrome or other.

Comment: Interesting, why it works ? I change padding 1px to 3px, the border is still missing.

Comment: you scale your div 0,7 , but the whole BOX-Model will scale down to this size, include your borders and the padding. and a border which is smaller than 1 px is laying BEHIND your div. if you add a padding of 1px, the border will become visible, and the padding is "behind" your div. it's hard to explain for me, because my english is horrible.